# how to find the microcontroller is big endian or little endian?

Tags: microcontroller

how to find the microcontroller is big endian or little endian ?

Without having the Microcontroller Specification ,How to know whether the controller is Big endian or Little Endian?

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
int x = 1;

if (*(char *)&x == 1)
    printf("Little Endian [LSB first]");  // or LED1 ON
else
    printf("Big Endian [MSB first]");     // or LED2 ON
```

What I'm doing here is -

- setting the least significant bit in an "int"
- de-referencing that "int"
- casting it to char pointer i.e. char array and
- then reading the first element of that array

If we are able to see our least significant bit '1' at first index, it means it is storing LSB first, which means **Little Endian system**.

If we are not able to see our least significant bit '1' at first index, it means it is storing MSB first, which means **Big Endian system**.

Answer (score 3):

You dont have the spec!? you can download it from the internet...

If you can run debugger on this controller , you can write 0x1234 to some RAM address and see in the memory window what the result:

I.E write 0x1234 to 0x2000 will result in:

0x2000 = 0x12 , 0x2001 = 0x34 --> big endian

0x2000 = 0x34 , 0x2001 = 0x12 --> little endian

Comment: In case debugger is not supported on this controller .Please let me know is there any alternative methods to find whether controller is Big Endian or Little Endian?

Comment: you dont have the spec and not have debugger. what do you have? part number of the uC? close box of uC hardware?

Comment: I have Nothing,this question was asked in interview.How you will ensure that the Microcontroller is Little Endian or Big Endian?

Comment: If someone was aksing me this question , my answer were be "I will get the datasheet and check it out" follow by my explanation on little and big endian to show my knowledge...

Comment: In an interview, they are looking for what code you would write to do detection.  You write a uint32_t* with 0x11223344, then read back the same pointer address cast as uint8_t*.  If little endian, you will read 0x44, if big endian you get 0x11

Comment: it sounds like they are trying to determine if you know the difference between big and little endian, and we can tell from the question that you do not.  You should do some research... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_endian to be fair ARM for example has confused the issue by using more than one definition, the current cores are byte invariant, so both big and little endian modes return the same byte for the same address.  for word invariant the same byte address returns different values.  Endianness is still detectable though